# Is there any equivalent code for asp.net web-form of MVC JsonResult and Json?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I want to solve this using ASP.Net Web Form. I am already able to do it on MVC. What should I do?

In controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetEnrolledCourseByStudentId(int stdId)
    {
        List<EnrolledCourse> enrolledCourseList = enrolledCourseManager.GetEnrolledCourseByStudentId(stdId);

        return Json(enrolledCourseList);
    }
```

In View (inside script):

```
            json = { stdId: id };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetEnrolledCourseByStudentId", "SaveResult")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#CourseId").empty();
                    $("#CourseId").append('<option value="">Select Course</option>');

                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        $("#CourseId").append('<option value="' + value.CourseId + '">' + value.CourseName + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: return a `string`.

Comment: You would need an [HttpHandler serving json](https://mikewaniewski.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/asp-net-http-handler-for-serving-json/)